# How to configure ufw-firewall for OpenVPN

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, vpn, openvpn

I am running a VPN via [IPredator](https://www.ipredator.se/) on Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop, which works perfectly, when ufw is disabled.

When I enable ufw, I logically cannot establish a connection. IPredator states that I have to meet the following IP-range to get things working:

```
First IP address: 46.246.32.0
Last IP address: 46.246.63.255
Net mask: 255.255.224.0
```

I already did a basic ufw configuration, following this [tutorial](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BasicSecurity/Firewall):

```
25,53,80,110,443/tcp       ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
53,67,68/udp               ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
51413/tcp                  ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
51413/udp                  ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
6969/tcp                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
25,53,80,110,443/tcp       ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)
53,67,68/udp               ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)
51413/tcp                  ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)
51413/udp                  ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)
6969/tcp                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)
```

How can I configure the mentioned IP-range in ufw?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IPredator is listening on port 1194:

```
sudo ufw allow out 1194/udp
```

This fixes the issue.